# How to pass 2 parameters to an action in a Controller MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Please excuse me if you find this question a bit silly.But I am quite new to MVC.

As far as I know that the actions are designed to work stateless. 
Therefore, The client should pass the ID's of the objects to Actions and we will use a repository (EF) to find the object and do what we like. My problem is that there is Many to Many relationship between Object and Artist.

When I am on the edit page of an Object I would like to find the Artist on the popup menu and add an Artist to the Object that I am editing. Therefore I have created a AddArtistToObject action in ObjectController as below

```
public ActionResult AddArtistToObject(int ObjectID, int ArtistID){
   //code goes here
  }
```

So the popup menu opens up and there is a search area to search for artist. you get the list of artist matching. Then every row has a select button. the select button href contains the ArtistID.

I believe that somehow I need to attach the ObjectID in the URL too.

the URL becomes like : http://domain.com/Object/AddArtistToObject/ArtistID 
and by using jquery I get the objectID and attach the ObjectID also in the URL to make the URL like http://domain.com/Object/AddArtistToObject/ArtistID/ObjectID

So for example the actual URL becomes 
http://domain.com/Object/AddArtistToObject/54/43

Don't you think that this URL is confusing as well? would not be better if I could change the URl something like http://domain.com/Object/AddArtistToObject?ObjectID=43+ArtistID=54

Then in the action I retrieve the Object and Artist by using the ids as below

```
var artist = repository.Artist.First(d=>d.ArtistID==ArtistID);

 repository.Object.First(d=>d.ObjectID==ObjectID).Artists.Add(artist);
  objectsRep.Update();
  objectsRep.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is that the routing does not end in this action at all. I put breakpoint but this action does not get called at all. How should I change the URL to get this action called? Also do you think that this approach is right or I should be reading more about MVC before I go ahead ? :)

Comment: What I know is that to pass more that one parameter you can do something like Url.Action("AddArtistToObject", "ControllerName", new { ObjectID = 2, ArtistID = 2 }) . The number can be your variables.

Answer (score 2):

> http://domain.com/Object/AddArtistToObject?ObjectID=43+ArtistID=54

It should be, replace **+** with **&**

> http://domain.com/Object/AddArtistToObject?ObjectID=43&ArtistID=54

Then your controller action will hit with default routes -

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

And the controller action is -

```
    public ActionResult AddArtistToObject(int ObjectID, int ArtistID)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Output -

[image]